# Sqoop - error while connecting to DB2 using ssl

Tags: ssl, db2, sqoop

I am trying to export data to DB2 database that enforces SSL connection. I am using the following sqoop command

```
sqoop export \

-Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement=500 \

-Dsqoop.export.statements.per.transaction=100 \

-D dfs.mapred.max.split.size=1048576 \

-D mapreduce.job.max.split.locations=100 \

-D mapred.job.name=MYSQOOP_CMD_${DATE} \

-Ddb2.jcc.sslConnection=true \

--driver com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver \

--connect jdbc:db2://${DB2HOST}:${PORT}/${DB2NAME}':sslConnection=true' \

--username ${DB2USER} \

--password ${DB2PASS} \

--table ${DB2TBL} \

--input-fields-terminated-by '\t' \

--lines-terminated-by '\n' \

--export-dir "${OUTPUTDIR}DATE=*/*" -m 100
```

However, sqoop complains about "Invalid database URL syntax" due to `:sslConnection=true` appended to JDBC URI. Looking for help to resolve this issue

Comment: yes, certificates have already been configured.. and it is DB2 LUW that I am trying to connect to. I have already tested SSL connection from my machine for QMF and it works fine.

Comment: yeah, it can access LUW as well.. I have sample db on my machine and use qmf to connect to it..

Comment: Each property-value pair in the URL, inlcuding the last one, must be terminated with a semicolon.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mule database connector url format for DB2 not correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26042064/mule-database-connector-url-format-for-db2-not-correct)

Comment: If you use `-Ddb2.jcc.sslConnection=true` then you don't need additional `:sslConnection=true;` on the URL.  But you might need to specify the keystore (and its password if using).

Comment: @mustaccio I tried using ; separator but that does not appear to solve the issue